# Identifying small objects in large noisy images - opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I need to identify a relatively small object (a clay pigeon) in large (1080p) images. The background is varied, in between buildings, trees, sky, anything really.

Im using OpenCV and have spent a good few weeks learning to use it, and met with some succes using a combination of inRange, Canny, Blur, HOWEVER this relies on identifying the clay pigeon only on colour:

```
public List<MatOfPoint> FindContours(Mat drawing, Scalar lowerBound, Scalar upperBound)
{
    Mat scratch = new Mat();
    Mat res = new Mat();

    Imgproc.blur(drawing, scratch, new Size(blur, blur));
    cvtColor(scratch, scratch, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Core.inRange(scratch, lowerBound, upperBound, scratch);
    Imgproc.Canny(scratch, res, threshold, threshold * 2, kernel_size);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(res, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    return contours;
}  

cal.lowerBoundTarget = new Scalar(0,84,19);
cal.upperBoundTarget = new Scalar(343,100,100);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = FindContours(src, cal.lowerBoundTarget, cal.upperBoundTarget);
```

The source image is a random image of a clay pigeon in flight.

The algorithm works reasonably well on simpler images like these:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiC1r.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3wz0.jpg

But with different lighting conditions and backgrounds it fails to identify the clay:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVy3M.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4PSA.jpg

I find that the HSV values of the clay varies greatly thus making it hard to identify, in fact the range I have concluded covers is very wide. Which is not very helpful.

Any ideas for a set of steps that will reliably identify the clay nomatter the background (within reason - i.e. backgrounds whose colours effectively make the clay invisible can be ignored).

Comment: Is the clay pigeon always the same color (in your case red)? If yes, you may want to search in color space

Comment: Hi, yes the colour of the clay is always the same (bright neon orange). However the lighting conditions will change based on background and weather etc, as well as camera calibration (to some degree). Thus, I cannot use a simple inRange.

Comment: @A.Claudi Seems bright neon orange - stable high contrast color and  search in color space is good approach. If you have not only one picture but frame-by-frame video you can use motion detection algorithms to improve accuracy.